# Remote debug with IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I try to debug my Java code remotely with IntelliJ Idea 10.5.
My code implements Java server running on Amazon using Tomcat.
I created Remote debug configuration in Idea, and this configuration behaves strange.

1. Configuration has only "Configuration" and "Logs" parts. "Server" and "Deployment" parts are missing.
2. When I choose it, "Run" button becomes unavailable. "Debug" button looks available, but when I press it, debug does not start.

What could be wrong?
How can I check if debug configuration is OK?

thank you.

Comment: Is debug enabled on the Tomcat JVM?

Comment: Amazon server may block connection to the debug port by default.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that server name started with http://
I removed 'http://' and it worked